# Cannot upload multiple files on Mac using fileInput

Tags: r, shiny

Using `fileInput()` to upload multiple files does not work on Mac. It works on Windows and Linux. I have also set argument `multiple=T`, but I am not able to select more than one file. Here is a working script.

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list( 
ui = bootstrapPage( 
tags$h2("Upload test app"), 
fileInput("finput","Upload files",multiple=TRUE), 
tableOutput("contents"), 
), 
server = function(input, output) {

output$contents <- renderTable({ 
input$finput}) 

} 
))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Safari web browser? Or something else on your Mac? Have you tried Chrome?

Comment: Ah. good point. I was in a virtual machine and only tried the RStudio browser. Installed chrome and it works fine.